# Can't load static image with Angular2 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

Usually I'm backend developer but started learn frontend stuff.
I made example app from Angular tutorial and trying to build my own small app now.

I stuck with simple problem - when I'm trying to load static image (ex. logo) it returns me 404 error code. Looks like I missed something in configuration and I have no idea what it can be.

---

Code for load image:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="48" height="48"/>
```

---

Structure:

```
web
- app
-- assets
-- images
-- js
-- model
-- stylesheets
-- *.ts
-- *.html
-- *.css
-- main.ts
-- polyfills.ts
-- rxjs-extensions.ts
-- vendor.ts
- config
- dist
- index.html
- packages.json
- tsconfig.json
- typings.json
- webpack.config.js
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --display-error-details --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

---

config/webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './app/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './app/vendor.ts',
        'app': './app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
    ]
};
```

---

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const webpack = require('webpack');

const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    debug: true,

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('app'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

---

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<catalog-root>Loading...</catalog-root>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `/` before `images`. All the paths will be relative to root, since your SPA is `index.html` located in root, I assume.

If not, add your base url in `<head>`

```
<base href="<%= webpackConfig.metadata.baseUrl %>">
```

Also, check if your are copying your assets correctly in your webpack:

`const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');`

```
plugins[
  ...,
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: 'app/images',
    to: './images'
  }]);
];
```

Comment: "/" - the same 404. There was <base href> in index.html. Should I added it in each page? The same result for all <base href> options provided by you.

Comment: No, just need to add in your index.html. Did you copy your assets in webpack?

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. I added CopyWebpackPlugin and build.

Comment: The problem is, in real world, parts of images are used by `Base64` url. `url-loader` can convert the image to `base64` url. So, copy the whole images directory doesn't make sense. What about the image size is just `1kb`? Do you really want to send a request to server for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative path. So eg if in main.ts:

```
<img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="48" height="48"/>
```

Comment: the same result: 404

Comment: what is appearing in your /dist folder if you do a build?   is the image appearing there?  Only stuff that would appear in the /dist folder would be available via the web server..

Comment: no, there are no any images in dist folder after build. There are app....js,  app...js.map, index.html, polyfills...js, polyfills...js.map, vendor...js, vendor....js.map. But styles and css are loaded fine.

Comment: I am the furthest thing from a webpack expert - but i remember recently having some grief related to images not loading on my most current project. I'm checking through my webpack config and not seeing anything that can assist you though...

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping you images in "assets" folder in the "src" folser of your angular app. then try to open in using `assets/myImage.jpg` in the HTML and `/src/assets/myImage.jpg` in the CSS